# C# Dictionary Constructor that which accepts a Func<string,bool> as a key

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, lambda, delegates

I have been going trough a TechEd about S.O.L.I.D principles and I am bit puzzled with one piece of code. I was not sure how to phrase the question as I am a bit confused.

I do have an idea of how delegates and generics work but I dont know how the guy is add values to the dictionary. The source code is below:

```
//Part of a static module/class outside the main program
private static readonly Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, IInputRetriever> InputRetrievers = new Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, IInputRetriever>(); 
//inside the same module/class at the source code above
public static IInputRetriever ForFileName(string filename)
    {
        return InputRetrievers.First(x => x.Key(filename)).Value;
    }
//Also inside the static class mentioned above
public static void RegisterInputRetriever(Func<string, bool> evaluator, IInputRetriever inputRetriever)
    {
        InputRetrievers.Add(evaluator, inputRetriever);
    }

//Called in the main program
private static void ConfigureStorage()
    {
        var blobStorage = new BlobDocumentStorage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageAccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageKey"]);
        var fileStorage = new FileDocumentStorage();
        var httpInputRetriever = new HttpInputRetriever();

        InputRetriever.RegisterInputRetriever(x => x.StartsWith("http"), httpInputRetriever);
        InputRetriever.RegisterInputRetriever(IsBlobstorageUrl, blobStorage);
        InputRetriever.RegisterInputRetriever(x => true, fileStorage);
        DocumentPersister.RegisterDocumentPersister(IsBlobstorageUrl, blobStorage);
        DocumentPersister.RegisterDocumentPersister(x => true, fileStorage);
    }
//Still inside the main program
    private static bool IsBlobstorageUrl(string str)
    {
        var storageAccount = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageAccount"];
        return str.StartsWith(string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", storageAccount));
    }

//Called in another module/class
var inputRetriever = InputRetriever.ForFileName(sourceFileName);
```

I guess what I want to know is, how does the "InputRetrievers" dictionary know what key to use for each entry?

My initial thoughts would be InputRetrievers.Add("The key",Value);
In this case, a delegate was used to populate the key, that is where I am confused.

Comment: I don't think it's an example of the _good_ code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method:

```
public static IInputRetriever ForFileName(string filename)
{
    return InputRetrievers.First(x => x.Key(filename)).Value;
}
```

Will loop over all dictionary entries and execute the `Func<string, bool>` of each key until it finds a hit (i.e. when the Func returns `true` for `filename`). Then it will return the value.

Comment: @CodeCoaster , Isnt that for retrieving the value for the given key which is filename?

Comment: Well I don't know what video you're watching and the source isn't available online, but this returns a "IInputRetreiver" that can "handle" the given "filename". What those concepts mean is probably explained in the video. I'm not sure how this demonstrates SOLID though. The code honestly doesn't look that well.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @CodeCasterThe source is available online : http://chris.59north.com/file.axd?file=2014%2f5%2fTechEd.Demo.SolidPrinciples.zip

Comment: @CodeNoob Ultimately `Dictionary` isn't the correct data structure for this since there are no key lookups.

Comment: @CodeCaster What I want to know, how are the dictionary Keys assigned to their respective values.

Comment: @CodeNoob I still don't get what you're asking. A `Dictionary` is a specialized collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, the `TKey` here is `Func<string, bool>`, and for example `x => true` is an instance of that type, but that's irrelevant - basically they are abusing the dictionary. It could as well have been a `List<Tuple<Tkey, TValue>>`. The key will be hashed for lookup (`GetHashCode()`).

Comment: @CodeNoob Are you asking how the hashing for the keys will work?  It's just going to use the default reference hashing.  Meaning two identical `Func`s could be in the dictionary twice because they are separate references.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Func<string,bool> will result in a function being called. Where does the input parameter come from?

Comment: @CodeNoob I really don't know what "input parameter" is supposed to mean. Anyway it is not that the _result_ of the `Func<string, bool>` will be used as a key - the expression itself will be.

Comment: Input parameter of Func<string,bool> is a "string" type in this case.

Comment: @CodeNoob The input parameter is `fiename` in the code `x.Key(filename)`

Comment: @juharr, so the value for filename will only be added to the dictionary object if the operator condition is true?

Comment: No, there won't be added anything to the dictionary. This code is registering "IInputRetrievers" in the dictionary, and later testing which IInputRetriever to use for a given filename by calling the `Func<string, bool>` from the dictionary's keys.

Comment: @CodeCaster , The dictionary "InputRetrievers" has data added to it with the Func<string,bool> being used as the key. O.M.G, It makes sense now. Thanks for the help, the filename is used in the delegate. The Func<string,bool> is called here "First(x => x.Key(filename)". Thanks guys.